# Как подключить базу данных sqlite?

Tags: c#

дорогой товарищ. Нужна помощь, я создал базу данных Sqlite и как мне её подключить к .net core проекту?
Я в менеджере пакетов пишу следующий код:
`Scaffold-DbContext "DataSource=C:\Users\comp\Desktop\Бот Telegram .NetCore\TelegramBot.sqlite3" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core`

Вроде всё должно работать, но при выполнении данной команды не создаются классы таблиц, а создаётся только context. HELP!

Comment: Возможно не играет значения, но везде пишут `Data Source` через пробел. А ещё ваш путь содержит пробелы, его нужно обернуть в ковычки.

Comment: Путь то содержит пробелы `...\Бот Telegram .NetCore\...` надо бы весь путь одинарными кавычками закрыть.

Comment: @Bulson как должен путь выглядит по итогу? Я сделал, но не работает. Напишите пожалуйста

Comment: Как-то так `"Data Source=\"C:\Users\comp\Desktop\Бот Telegram .NetCore\TelegramBot.sqlite3\""`

Comment: @SmorcIRL, к сожалению так не работает)

Comment: Простите пожалуйста за отобранное у вас время, я имбицил насоздавал БД, что в названиях запутался, оказывается что БД к которой я пытался подключится она пустая)

Comment: @ДмитрийСтепанов, тогда удалите, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос.